# Gazebo crashes when sensors are added to ShadowHand

Tags: ros, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After adding the following section to *model/hand_urdf/thumb/thdistal.urdf.xacro* in the *sr_hand* package Gazebo crashes during startup.

```
<gazebo reference="thdistal">
  <sensor:contact name="thdistal_contact_sensor">
    <geom>distal_collision_geom</geom>    
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>    
    <controller:gazebo_ros_bumper name="thdistal_gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>    
      <updateRate>100.0</updateRate> 
      <frameName>thdistal</frameName>  
      <bumperTopicName>thdistal_bumper</bumperTopicName>
      <interface:bumper name="thdistal_gazebo_ros_bumper_iface" />
    </controller:gazebo_ros_bumper>    
  </sensor:contact>
  <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
</gazebo>
```

If I comment out the  and the first  tags Gazebo starts, but no contact messages are published.

All log files indicate that everything should be fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9335/gazebo-crashes-when-sensors-are-added-to-shadowhand/) by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I faced a similar problem and found the following resolution to work: construct the geom tag by appending _geom to the link name.

In your case, since the link name is thdistal, changing

`distal_collision_geom`
to
`thdistal_geom`

should avoid crashing gazebo on launch and enable the contact messages.
The reason might have something to do with how the urdf is translated to the format understood by gazebo. (look at urdf2gazebo.cpp)

Also, as was mentioned in the previous answer, I found that contact messages were generated only when the link geometry is in contact.

---

Originally posted by [rld](https://answers.ros.org/users/321/rld/) with karma: 26 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-03-22**:
That works! Thank you so very much!

**Comment by [erikjber](https://answers.ros.org/users/254/erikjber/) on 2011-03-22**:
I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way gazebo_ros_bumper plugin is constructed right now, no messages are published unless the geom is in contact.  This seems to be the wrong default behavior, so I've ticketed it [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4872), and a patch is in trunk.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1